# Error when declaring list in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists, nameerror

Here is a small piece of Python code to add elements of a nested list:

```
def nested_sum(lists):
    s = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  # If I delete this line then an error is given
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        s[i] = sum(lists[i])
    print sum(s)

lists = [[1],[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ]
nested_sum(lists)
```

Please excuse the formatting.

Issue with this code lies in the line I have commented.

The error shown was:

```
NameError: global name 's' is not defined
```

How can I avoid this error without declaring the list `s` before?

Comment: Because without that line your `s` variable is not defined...

Comment: nested_sum = lambda lists: sum(map(sum, lists))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you always have to declare list. But you can choose how. For example:

1) `s = [0] * len(lists)` - will be equal to your declaration

2) `s = []`, next you do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(lists)):
    s.append(sum(lists[i]))
```

Comment: But be careful when multiplying a list like that if there's mutable values in them, or the next question you will be asking is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) one. ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you delete the marked line you get a `NameError` because you try to index into something (`s`) before defining what that name should refer to. That should be clear.

The easiest way to solve your problem in one go is to us a generator expression in conjunction with `sum` with or without the `chain` function from `itertools` (depending on your preference).

Without `chain`:

```
>>> lists = [[1],[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ]
>>> sum(value for sublist in lists for value in sublist)
56
```

With `chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sum(chain(*lists))
56
```

which is equivalent to

```
>>> sum(chain.from_iterable(lists))
56
```

Comment: But OP wants the sum of sums, so rather `sum(map(sum, lists))`

Comment: @tobias_k edited. Using `sum` twice seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your for loop to a oneliner so you don't have to pre-declare the variable `s`. Here is the code:

```
def nested_sum(lists):
    s = [sum(lists[i]) for i in range(len(lists))]  #converted for loop to oneliner
    print sum(s)

lists = [[1],[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ]
nested_sum(lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in your case you don't actually need `s` to achieve the same functionality (if you don't mind altering the contents of `lists`):

```
def nested_sum(lists):
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        lists[i] = sum(lists[i])
    print sum(lists)

>>> lists = [[1],[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ]
>>> nested_sum(lists)
56
```

Comment: This will change the original list. Not sure OP wants to do this.

Comment: I have stated that clearly, if the OP isn't interested and let's me know I'll obviously delete/edit my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use a variable to store the sum rather than a list and use the 'in' keyword to iterate through the list items rather than a range:

```
def nested_sum(lists):
    list_sum = 0
    for i in lists:
        list_sum += sum(i)
    print (list_sum)

lists = [[1],[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ]

nested_sum(lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any intermediate list (and no extra memory, as per the comment by Lol4t0)

```
def nested_sum(lists):
    print sum(sum(l) for l in lists)
```

the syntax I've used is a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Of course it is much more flexible to declare your function w/o the `print`,

```
def nested_sum(lists):
    return sum(sum(l) for l in lists)
```

and then use it like this

```
l = [[1],[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ]
print nested_sum(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter and more pythonic way of doing that:

```
>>> lists = [[2,4], [1]]
>>> [sum(x) for x in lists]
```

output:
[6, 1]

You can read further on list comprehensions